# Can the parties who sign a building permit be liable in any way, shape or form of water damage to a building?

Tags: water, waterproofing, construction, building-regulations, building

Suppose you have a condo building.  That condo building was built 10 years ago.  The statutes of limitations is only good for 6 years (for negligence purposes).  There is water damage to the condo's exterior, and was discovered 10 years after construction.  There was no claim tied to the damage and starts just below the roof.  So the insurance company insuring the condo association (exterior and common areas of the building) won't reimburse because there's no actual event that caused this damage.

The construction company who built the building disintegrated their company and now have a different name.

During the construction, there were building permits signed for the construction, HVAC, electrical, plumbing, etc...

There were three parties involved with the building permits.  The owner (a realtor), the former construction company (who doesn't exist anymore) and the city building inspector.

This might be for a different StackExchange site, but....

Can the unit owners sue the parties (who are left) who signed the building permits if the water damage was due to faulty construction and should have met building codes?  (is there liability) Or do building permits just give permission to build?  And we could perhaps file a claim with the insurance company of the two parties left.  Or is that not an option?

Basically it will cost about the same to fix as it cost to build the building.  So we're basically SOL.

Comment: Upvoted because I'm interested to hear if an inspector/AHJ has ever been held responsible. (I have doubts that they would, unless something actually criminal could be proved...)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a legal question, not a do-it-yourself home improvement question.

Comment: This question should be directed to your lawyer, not a bunch of jokers on the internet.

Comment: Finding an honest lawyer is like finding an honest politician.